# Non UK company hiring local staffing

Tags: united-states, income-tax, united-kingdom

Do I need to issue any tax form to the local staffing we hired in UK for a small event? We are an Event company based in US.

Comment: I would strongly advise getting your staff through a UK-based agency that employs them rather than go through the hassle of setting up as an employer with HMRC and running your own payroll for a one-off event.

Comment: @MikeScott not to mention all the other legal formalities needed to employ staff in the UK

Answer (score 1):

Given the event occurred in the past, it might make sense to call HMRC (they are actually quite helpful) and sort out the formalities.

According to HMRC:

> Employees’ rights
> Anyone you employ must:
>
> - have an employment contract
> - be given payslips
> - not work more than the maximum hours allowed per week
> - be paid at least the National Minimum Wage
>
> If they meet the eligibility requirements, they’re also entitled to things like:
>
> - Statutory Maternity Pay
> - Statutory Sick Pay
> - paid holiday
> - redundancy pay
> - a workplace pension

It is obviously unlikely they meet the eligibility requirements for the other things, but you will need to sort out the payslips (the contract was likely verbal).

Some payroll companies can do the payslips for you, but may be less willing to do a one-off.  A local accountant may be able to help you out and/or a solicitor (type of attorney), as they deal with these things all the time.

You don't need to use the accountant or solicitor, as the forms are usually straightforward enough to do by oneself (unlike US tax forms), but they are different.

The payslips have to be provided within 7 days of being paid, and you will have needed information from the employees (e.g. their PAYE tax code and National Insurance number).